# How to show all data where date is earlier than today laravel

Tags: laravel, date, controller, where-clause, php-carbon

I`ve got code that shows all of the placements for a user. Is there a way to narrow this down to only show placements that are in the future? I've tried to do this using where and carbon::now to no avail.

My current code to show all of the placements :

```
$placements = Auth::user()->placementsAuthored;
$placements->load('keystage', 'subject', 'dates');
```

Placements Authored connection to connect a user to a placement :

```
public function placementsAuthored()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Placement::class, 'author_id');
}
```

My attempt at trying to do this. I get no errors but the code doesn't work. It doesn't seem to take any effect of my where clause any ideas?

```
$placements ->where('date','>',Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: try this `->whereDate('date', '<=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))`

Comment: Hey yeah, i tried that. When I do that for some reason I get the following error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereDate does not exist.` . And I'm not sure why?

Comment: Your laravel version?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "^9.19"

Comment: I get this error when I try that : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::load()`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tweaking, I found that this works but I don't understand why this works and the above doesn't. In my mind, they do the same but this is a longer way of doing it. Any idea why this works and the above doesn't?

```
// Only load future placements
$placements = Placement::whereHas( 'dates',
    function ($q) {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $q->where('author_id', $user_id)->where('date','>=' ,Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));})->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

You should take a different `name` for the `date column` because the `date` keyword is already reserved in the `PHP function` this is not a standard way

Comment: Is that what's causing the issue?

Comment: Pretty sure MySQL doesn't care if there's a PHP function with the same name

Comment: Oh ok because changing this could take me a while and I would rather not if I can avoid it